# Can't authenticate on Rails with BCrypt - password hashes are different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, hash

I am trying to create a simple authentication system but I seem to have a problem.

The signup process works fine, but when I try to login with the exact same information, I can't (I get "Invalid email or password"). As I saw, the hash comparison returns false. Here is my code:

```
#sessions_controller.rb

def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :password
before_save :encrypt_password

validates_confirmation_of :password
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email

def self.authenticate(email, password)
  user = User.where(email: email).first
  # throw Exception.new(user.password_hash) #uncaught throw #<Exception: $2a$10$9FHhPyb7BW01ktwTTgZHX.hlKKv4ajX/dX9D/xNGmZoajJTdGG4N.>
  # throw Exception.new(user.password_salt) #uncaught throw #<Exception: $2a$10$9FHhPyb7BW01ktwTTgZHX.>
  # throw Exception.new(BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)) #uncaught throw #<Exception: $2a$10$9FHhPyb7BW01ktwTTgZHX.O62xalJit020Jb0g5XDdB5V8dGMslQS>
  if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
  else
    nil
  end
end

def encrypt_password
  if password.present?
    self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
    self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
  end
end
end
```

So, as you can see in the commented lines in user.rb, the password hash that I get when trying to log in is not the same with the original one. Obviously, the password I enter is the correct one.

```
user.password_hash = $2a$10$9FHhPyb7BW01ktwTTgZHX.hlKKv4ajX/dX9D/xNGmZoajJTdGG4N.
user.password_salt = $2a$10$9FHhPyb7BW01ktwTTgZHX.
BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt) = $2a$10$9FHhPyb7BW01ktwTTgZHX.O62xalJit020Jb0g5XDdB5V8dGMslQS
```

Can you please give me a hint here? What is that I do wrong?

Thanks a lot!

---

//later edit: also adding the users controller, perhaps this can help.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end   
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.fetch(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) if params[:user]
    end

end
```

---

Edit: posting the logs for signing up/logging in

```
Started GET "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:23:13 +0300
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (31.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 41.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)


Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:24:30 +0300
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LPLEs9at6BLGgjikYynnEzA/JAMMVl9IYGId1zEyNEg=", "user"=>{"name"=>"johntest", "email"=>"johntest@johntest.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'johntest@johntest.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `email`, `name`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-10-11 08:24:30', 'johntest@johntest.com', 'johntest', '$2a$10$tpDFvkFUC.OPckDm6xacU.xkjFmECg2CDpsi3cjTJNX6K58ujHOn6', '$2a$10$tpDFvkFUC.OPckDm6xacU.', '2013-10-11 08:24:30')
   (39.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 141ms (ActiveRecord: 40.0ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:24:30 +0300
Processing by TroublesController#frontpage as HTML
  Trouble Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `troubles`.* FROM `troubles`
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `troubles`.* FROM `troubles`
  Rendered troubles/_marker_infowindow.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered troubles/_marker_infowindow.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.6/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered troubles/frontpage.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 13.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

[...](loading assets)

Started GET "/log_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:24:52 +0300
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 12.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 11:25:05 +0300
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LPLEs9at6BLGgjikYynnEzA/JAMMVl9IYGId1zEyNEg=", "name"=>"johntest", "email"=>"johntest@johntest.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'johntest@johntest.com' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 10.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

[...](loading assets)
```

So I went to the sign up page, filled in the details, I was forwarded to the homepage and it said "Signed up!". I clicked login, entered the details and it says "Invalid email or password".

Comment: the password is obviously not the one you hashed :) otherwise this would work as expected. are you sure that there were no whitespaces or special characters involved?

Comment: I'd recommend using devise instead of reinventing the wheel. You're much safer using devise than your own authentication system. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: The bcrypt-handling code looks ok, so most likely the value of `password` is not the same as when the hash was generated. Finding out what it *was* is not really possible, unless you have an inspiration as to what went wrong during development or testing.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But I am 1000% sure the password is the same. Tried this not only once, but with various accounts and multiple passwords - they were always correctly written. Can this be some sort of bug then?

Comment: It is possible for the typed password to be the same in both interactions, but due to a bug (e.g. in sequence of operations, or in string handling) not visible in your code for the value returned by `password` to *not* be the same each time.

Comment: Ok, tried this again. Fresh server start, no bugs, create a new user and tried to log in. But I have the same problem..

Comment: Added the users controller too, maybe that can help. Thanks!

Comment: go to `config/application.rb` and set `config.filter_parameters = []` restart the app, create a user and try to login. get all the logs involved and post them here. after you did that, we can confirm if there is a bug in bcrypt (extremely unlikely) or in your data handling (99,9999 likely).

Comment: Ok, just did that. Posted the logs at the end of the question.

Comment: @watt password is still filtered, that should not be the case! if you reset the filter_parameters!

Comment: @phoet I did as you told, I pasted exactly `config.filter_parameters = []` in `application.rb`..

Comment: @watt there must be some other place where you change that configuration. otherwise there would be something like this in your log `Parameters: {"password"=>"12345"}`

Comment: Getting closer! From the logs, the first password, as saved to the database is "password".  `BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret( "password", '$2a$10$tpDFvkFUC.OPckDm6xacU.' )
    == "$2a$10$tpDFvkFUC.OPckDm6xacU.xkjFmECg2CDpsi3cjTJNX6K58ujHOn6"`. As that is not the same as your exception instrumentation shows, I would hazard a guess that the data is saving correctly, but you are passing wrong or mangled params to session `create`

Comment: Thanks, Neil. This is my login form responsible for passing parameters to session `create`.
`<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <%= label_tag :name %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>

  <%= label_tag :email %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>

  <%= label_tag :password %>
  <%= password_field :password, params[:password] %>

  <%= submit_tag "Log in" %>
  
<% end %>`
so it should be okay...

Comment: @watt: Keep working on removing the filters, they might tell you what happened. Could you also supply the failed hash for the case when you input "password" (as per the log, in the third uncaught throw, but when you input "password")?

Comment: @NeilSlater thank you very much for your replies, but I finally decided to give up and install OmniAuth instead. It seemed pretty easy to install.
Anyway, thanks again for taking the time and trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Bcrypt is decrypting the right way but the culprit in your code is the **before_save :encrypt_password** just change the before save event as **before_create** event. with before_save , Every time you update the user record encrypt_password is called and it is encrypting the password field that way you are losing the first encrypted password which never matches though you give the correct password. I got stuck up with the same issue, after a deep analysis I got to know the fix.

Comment: This is gold. Not sure if it was the OP's issue, this was exactly my problem when trying to roll my own account email confirmation setup.